# Is it possible consumer Kafka messages after arrival?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to consume events from a kafka topic after the time they arrive. The time on which I want the event to be consumed is in the payload of the message. Is it possible to achieve something like that in Kafka? What are the drawbacks of it?

Practical example: a message M is produced at 12:10, arrives to my kafka topic at 12:11 and I want the consumer to poll it at 12:41 (30 minutes after arrival)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has a default retention period of all topic for 7 days. You can therefore consume up to a week's data at any moment, the drawback being network saturation if you are constantly doing this.

If you want to consume data that is not at the latest offset, then for any new consumer group, you would set `auto.offset.reset=earliest`. Otherwise for existing groups, you would need to use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset` command in order to re-consume an already consumed record.

Sometimes you may want to start from beginning of a topic, for example, if you have a compacted topic, in order to rebuild the "deltas" of the data within a topic - lookup the "Stream / Table Duality"

> The time on which I want the event to be consumed is in the payload of the message

Since [KIP-32](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message) every message has a timestamp outside the payload, by the way

> I want the consumer to poll it ... (30 minutes after arrival)

Sure, you can start a consumer whenever, as long as the data is within the retention window, you will get that event.

There isn't a way to finely control *when* that happens that other than acually making your consumer at that time, for example 30 minutes later. You could play with `max.poll.records` and `max.poll.interval.ms`, but I find anything larger than a few seconds really isn't a use-case for Kafka.

For example, you could rather have a `TimerTask` around a consumer thread, or Spark or MapReduce scheduled with an Oozie/Airflow task that reads a max amount of records.

Comment: why should I use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset`? I am not sure the timestamp outside the payload might work for my use-case. I edited the question with a practical example

Comment: If you already had an active consumer group, and you had consumed the messages, then you need to reset the group to go-backwards

Comment: And in the Producer API, you can make `new ProducerRecord` with or without a timestamp. If you don't set it, then it'll use the current system time, which might be approximately your payload time anyway

Comment: I also don't want to start the consumer later on; the consumer should keep listening to new messages but I should find a way to inspect the content of a message to decide when actually that message is fully consumed

Comment: That is definitely possible, so I don't understand the problem

Comment: my consumer will read the message and then `sleep` until the time inside the message is less than the current time; afterwards, the message will be fully consumed. Meanwhile all the other messages are waiting in the queue. This means that all the messages need to have the same delay, right?

Comment: Conceptually, I'm not following, other than you're trying to do micro-batching for some un-determined amount of records. You would need to do a `poll(timeout)`, which gives some records, then you deserialize and inspect some data in them, and look at a timestamp... Then you want to drop the events after a certain time, and commit only the consumed "good" timed events? Then sleep and repeat on the next poll? Note: the poll timeout essentially *is* the sleep action here.

Comment: if I poll at time _t_ an event and this event has a "message" time of _t+10_, I want to wait 10 and then process it, without meanwhile consuming anything else

Comment: Then I would suggest emitting the records into a type of priority queue sorted by time on a background thread, rather than blocking the Kafka poll loop, which doesn't like when you take longer than `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms`, for example